# Populate Input for component inside mat-dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

Currently we have like 5-10 different dialogs and we add data using @Inject (`@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: DialogData,`)

```
this.dialog.open(MyComponent, {
  data: { data: this.dataToPass }
});
```

But I was kind of curious if there is another way?
Would love to have it similar to this:

```
this.dialog.open(MyComponent, {
  input1: { this.dataToPass },
  input2: { this.moreDataToPass }
});
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: unfortunately No, Mat-Dialog has only one field data which is used as a collection of all data .

Comment: you could use a Observable Subject

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
this.MyComponent_dialog_ref= this.dialog.open( MyComponent );
this.MyComponent_dialog_ref.componentInstance.input1= this.dataToPass;
this.MyComponent_dialog_ref.componentInstance.input2= this.moreDataToPass;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject this in your dialog component in the constructor

```
constructor(
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateProductListModalComponent>,
  private dialog: MatDialog,
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { yourDataName: any },
) { }
```

and in when you try to open the dialog do this:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YourComponent, {
  width: '300px',
  height: '300px',
  data: { yourDataName: yourData },
})
```